# Where can I find the python Tools directory?

Tags: python-2.7

The python2.7 documentation refers to a Tools/scripts directory and a Tools/demos directory, but those don't seem to be on my computer.

```
    locate Tools/scripts
```

doesn't find anything.

A post on this site said that

```
    sudo apt-get source python
```

would download the Tools directory, but it did not.  Have you any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you enable and update the sources repository before the `apt-get`?

Comment: I'm a linux newbie, so perhaps not.  The first time I tried the command it failed with an error message that told me to install dev-dpkg.  I did so, and the command seemed to run Ok the second time.  What else should I have done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Tools/scripts` files are installed with the [`python2.7-examples`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/all/python2.7-examples/filelist) package, in Ubuntu. They are located in the `/usr/share/doc/python2.7/examples/Tools/scripts` directory once the package is installed.

Comment: Not on my system./usr/share/doc/python2.7
ACKS.gz              copyright           python-policy.sgml.gz  README.gz
changelog.Debian.gz  NEWS.gz             python-policy.txt.gz
changelog.gz         python-policy.html  README.Debian

Comment: $ ls /usr/share/doc/python2.7
ACKS.gz              copyright           python-policy.sgml.gz  README.gz
changelog.Debian.gz  NEWS.gz             python-policy.txt.gz
changelog.gz         python-policy.html  README.Debian

Comment: And what does `dpkg -l python2.7-examples` say?

Comment: Not on my system.  I have a /usr/share/doc/python2.7 director, but it has no example subdirectory.  I believe that python 2.7 was the default when I installed ubuntu 12.04.  Do you mean something else by, "when the package is installed?"  Thanks.

Comment: Re-read the answer. The package you need to install is `python2.7-examples` not `python2.7`.